# My program fails to launch when compiled with AddressSanitizer

Tags: c++, gcc, address-sanitizer

When I compile and link my project with address sanitizer enabled `-fsanitize=address` on GCC 12.1, the program crashes at startup with following error message

```
==2795970==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:10064 "((__interception::real_memcpy)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    <empty stack>
```

This seems to happen before `main()`. The program runs fine when not compiled with `-fsanitize=address`.

Comment: How to reproduce your problem? On godbolt it seems [to work just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/jafr3zjj5) without any additional flags.

Answer (score 1):

The project also compiles a shared library which I forgot to consider. When linked to libasan statically with `-static-libasan`, everything works as expected.